# Why use Arrow's Options instead of Kotlin nullable

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, arrow-kt

I was having a look at the Arrow library found [here](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow). Why would ever want to use an `Option` type instead of Kotlin's built in nullables?

Comment: already read the docs? http://arrow-kt.io/docs/datatypes/option/

Comment: @s1m0nw1 That states "*Kotlin tries to solve the problem by getting rid of null values altogether and providing its own special syntax Null-safety machinery based on `?`.*" and "*Arrow models the absence of values through the Option datatype similar to how Scala, Haskell and other FP languages handle optional values.*" It does not provide any comparison between the two approaches.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: If you really want to have a detailed talk about why *Arrow* is useful, then please head over to https://soundcloud.com/user-38099918/arrow-functional-library and listen to one of the people who work on it. *(5:35min)*

The people who create and use that library simple want to use Kotlin differently than the people who created it and use ["the Option datatype similar to how Scala, Haskell and other FP languages handle optional values"](http://arrow-kt.io/docs/datatypes/option/).

This is just another way of defining return types of values that you do not know the output of.

Let me show you three versions:

**nullability in Kotlin**

```
val someString: String? = if (condition) "String" else null
```

**object with another value**

```
val someString: String = if (condition) "String" else ""
```

**the Arrow version**

```
val someString: Option<String> = if (condition) Some("String") else None
```

A major part of Kotlin logic can be to never use [nullable types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) like `String?`, but you will need to use it when interopting with Java. When doing that you need to use safe calls like `string?.split("a")` or the [not-null assertion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator) `string!!.split("a")`.

I think it is perfectly valid to use safe calls when using Java libraries, but the [Arrow guys](https://github.com/arrow-kt) seem to think different and want to use their logic all the time.

The benefit of using the Arrow logic is ["empowering users to define pure FP apps and libraries built atop higher order abstractions. Use the below list to learn more about Λrrow's main features"](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow).

Comment: To the question "why should I use `Option` instead of nullables" I would expect concrete reasons/advantages, especially given the additional syntax overhead and non-conformity with standard types. However this answer merely states "so you can use Kotlin in a different way".

Answer (score 33):

I have been using the `Option` data type provided by Arrow for over a year, and there at the beginning, we did the exact same question to ourselves. The answer follows.

## Option vs Nullable

If you compare just the `option` data type with `nullables` in Kotlin, they are almost even. Same semantics (there is some value or not), almost same syntax (with Option you use `map`, with nullables you use [safe call operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls)).

But when using `Options`, you enable the possibility to take benefits from the arrow ecosystem!

## Arrow ecosystem (functional ecosystem)

When using `Options`, you are using the `Monad Pattern`. When using the monad pattern with libraries like [arrow](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow), [scala cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats), [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz), you can take benefits from several functional concepts. Just 3 examples of benefits (there is a lot more than that):

#### 1. Access to other Monads

`Option` is not the only one! For instance, `Either` is a lot useful to **express** and **avoid to throw** Exceptions. `Try`, `Validated` and `IO` are examples of other common monads that help us to do (in a better way) things we do on typical projects.

#### 2. Conversion between monads + abstractions

You can easily convert one monad to another. You have a `Try` but want to return (and express) an `Either`? Just convert to it. You have an `Either` but doesn't care about the error? Just convert to `Option`.

```kotlin
val foo = Try { 2 / 0 }
val bar = foo.toEither()
val baz = bar.toOption()
```

This abstraction also helps you to create functions that doesn't care about the container (monad) itself, just about the content. For example, you can create an extension method `Sum(anyContainerWithBigDecimalInside, anotherContainerWithBigDecimal)` that works with **ANY MONAD** (to be more precise: *"to any instance of applicative"*) this way:

```kotlin
fun <F> Applicative<F>.sum(vararg kinds: Kind<F, BigDecimal>): Kind<F, BigDecimal> {
    return kinds.reduce { kindA, kindB ->
        map(kindA, kindB) { (a, b) -> a.add(b) }
    }
}
```

A little complex to understand, but very helpful and easy to use.

#### 3. Monad comprehensions

Going from nullables to monads is not just about changing safe call operators to `map` calls. Take a look at the "binding" feature that arrow provides as the implementation of the pattern "Monad Comprehensions":

```kotlin
fun calculateRocketBoost(rocketStatus: RocketStatus): Option<Double> {
    return binding {
        val (gravity) = rocketStatus.gravity
        val (currentSpeed) = rocketStatus.currentSpeed
        val (fuel) = rocketStatus.fuel
        val (science) = calculateRocketScienceStuff(rocketStatus)
        val fuelConsumptionRate = Math.pow(gravity, fuel)
        val universeStuff = Math.log(fuelConsumptionRate * science)

        universeStuff * currentSpeed
    }
}
```

All the functions used and also the properties from `rocketStatus` parameter in the above example are `Options`. Inside the `binding` block, the `flatMap` call is abstracted for us. The code is a lot easier to read (and write) and you don't need to check if the values are present, if some of them is not, the computation will stop and the result will be an Option with `None`!

Now try to imagine this code with null verifications instead. Not just `safe call operators` but also probably `if null then return` code paths. A lot harder isn't it?

Also, the above example uses `Option` but the true power about monad comprehensions as an abstraction is when you use it with monads like [IO](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/effects/io/#io) in which you can abstract asynchronous code execution in the exact same "clean, sequential and imperative" way as above :O

## Conclusion

I strongly recommend you to start using monads like `Option`, `Either`, etc as soon as you see the concept fits the semantics you need, even if you are not sure if you will take the other big benefits from the functional ecosystem or if you don't know them very well yet. Soon you'll be using it without noticing the learning-curve. In my company, we use it in almost all Kotlin projects, even in the object-oriented ones (which are the majority).

Comment: A few nullable extension functions and the rocket status stuff can be reduced to `rocketStatus.gravity?.pow(rocketStatus.fuel)?.times(calculateRocketScienceStuff(rocketStatus))?.log2()?.times(rocketStatus.currentSpeed)` which in my opinion is much simpler and it ihas zero cost.

Comment: @Fleshgrinder it may be personal preference but for me this code is a lot harder to understand and to debug than the imperative version showed in my example. Also if you need to write extension functions (and obviously to mantain it) it has a cost.

Comment: And that was an isolated example. With monad comprehensions we can do other things, like for example to abstract in the same simple and imparative way asynchronous operations

Answer (score 6):

One thing other answers haven't mentioned: you can have `Option<Option<SomeType>>` where you can't have `SomeType??`. Or `Option<SomeType?>`, for that matter. This is quite useful for compositionality. E.g. consider [Kotlin's `Map.get`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/get.html):

> ```
> abstract operator fun get(key: K): V?
> ```
>
> Returns the value corresponding to the given key, or `null` if such a key is not present in the map.

But what if `V` is a nullable type? Then when `get` returns `null` it can be because the map stored a null value for the given key or because there was no value; you can't tell! If it returned `Option<V>`, there wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: But you can use `Optional<T?>` in this case and you have `containsKey`.

Comment: 1. Yes, it's explicitly mentioned in the answer. But then you still need `Option`, which is what the question is about. 2. Using `containsKey` is worse in at least two ways: accessing the map twice isn't free; in a concurrent program the key can be removed by another thread between `containsKey` and `get` calls.

Comment: I didn't consider `Option` and `Optional ` to be the same. Concurrency is a different issue, you have synchronized for that. In any event,  it's an extremely narrow use case that I've only ever encountered in caches.

Comment: If you mean the Java `Optional`, then of course `Optional<T?>` won't work; it doesn't allow nulls.

Comment: `val value: String? = mapOf<String, Optional<String>>()["k"]?.orElse(null)` goal achieved as we can now distinguish between missing key (get returns null) and a null value (optional is empty). This is how pretty much every cache implementation works that allows null values to be stored.